# For loop overwrites td instead of creating new each time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render new rows of td by reverse looping over incoming data from the following functions but it keeps overwriting the existing one.

```
reverseLoopOverArray = () => {
    for(let t = this.props.receivedData.length - 1; t >= 0; t--){
        return this.renderRow(this.props.receivedData[t], t);            
    }
}

renderRow = (item, index) => {
    return (
         <tr key={index} style={warning}>
            <td>{item.one}</td>
            <td>{item.two}</td>
            <td>{item.three}</td>
        </tr>
    )
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your loop will only run once, because you return in the first iteration.

Comment: Shouldn't it return for each item in the array?

Comment: No, it won't: https://jsfiddle.net/j58w1qtg/

Comment: Ah I see. So what's the fix then?

Comment: use map?  But you'll want to reverse first.

Comment: If I do reverse on the map, it for whatever reason screws up the ordering of the data. That's why I tried good old for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build an array and return that:

```
reverseLoopOverArray = () => {
    const rows = [];
    for(let t = this.props.receivedData.length - 1; t >= 0; t--){
        rows.push(this.renderRow(this.props.receivedData[t], t));            
    }
    return rows;
}
```

Comment: D'oh.. so simple! Worked like a charm. Thanks! I still wanna know why running map over the reverse array `this.props.receivedData.reverse().map` messes up the td's. Like it would not generate td's for some elements and for some it will. Really odd.

Comment: `map` would work just as well. Note that `reverse` modifies the array in place, which you shouldn't be doing on something that comes in via `props`.

Comment: What's the significance of `reverse` being in place in this case?

Comment: The component shouldn't modify any data that's being passed via props.